# Spring Boot Logging Configuration

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

Is there a way to disable Spring boot logs and print only the logs which i give in the program using logger.info or logger.debug statements. I mean i want only the log statements which i had given in the program to be logged and nothing else. I use the default logging system given by spring boot. If required i can change to log4j or log4j2 as well. Using spring-boot version 1.2.7.
In other way, putting forward , like logging.level.org.springframework can be used to log spring related logs ,is there a way like logging.level.applicationlevel to get application(Java logger statement) logs alone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure your logging in your application.properties like below:

```
logging.level.com.myapp.packagename=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR
```

INFO means it will print logging of classes in your package and all sub package at INFO/ERROR/WARN level, while for spring related classes only print if there are ERROR level logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure logging properties as follows:

logging.level.* = ERROR 
logging.level.**package_name**=DEBUG

**Example:** 
logging.level.com.example.controller=DEBUG

So classes under **com.example.controller** package will be logged, others only on error will be logged.

I hope this helped!!